# Does pypy handle threads and sockets quickly compared to hand written C?

Tags: python, c, multithreading, sockets, pypy

Does pypy handle threads and sockets quickly compared to hand written C? Compared to normal python?

I would just try it, but the python code in question was written for a small cluster of computers on which I am not an admin. I'm asking here because my attempts to google only provided comparisons to cython, unladen swallow, ect., and I don't want to bug the admin about it if this is unlikely to work.

I don't actually need pypy to be as good at C; I'm looking to use it because right now the interpreter's overhead is completely overshadowing the computation I'm trying to time. I just need pypy to get me in the neighborhood of handwritten C.

Comment: Have you considered just trying it with a small script?

Comment: Are "waiting for the socket" or "starting and stopping threads" really the CPU-bound performance bottlenecks of your application? If they are, you might want to wait for the sockets using select() and get rid of the parallelism attempt. Have you done profiling of the original code?

Comment: It's for sure slower (unless you use some nice library beating the one included in C program). JIT is a nice feature, access times will still suffer though and JIT can use much more ram.
I'm not fan of network things with garbage collectors though.

Comment: How do you know that the interpreter overhead is dominant? And if you are running this program on a cluster, why are you using threads? If you use sockets already to share data with instances on other machines, why not use sockets and the multiprocessing module to run multiple instances on one machine as well? That will get you around the global interpreter lock.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Does pypy handle threads and sockets quickly compared to hand written C?

No. It's usually the same or worse.

PyPy retains the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL) that CPython has. This means native threads cannot run Python code in parallel. Python threads also have additional semantics that come at a cost. Much synchronization surrounds Python thread start-up, shutdown, and tracking of the thread objects. By comparison, C threads will start up faster, are cheaper to use, and can run completely in parallel.

Efficient socket handling requires minimizing time not spent waiting for the next socket event. Since PyPy's threading model is still bound by the GIL, this means threads that return from blocking socket calls can't proceed until they acquire the GIL. Equivalent C code generally executes faster, and can return to waiting on socket events sooner.

> Compared to normal python?

Yes. But not much.

For the reasons above, PyPy will, except for occasional spikes due to JIT and and other overheads, require less CPU time for the equivalent code. Therefore both thread and socket handling is faster and more responsive.

> I would just try it, but the python code in question was written for a small cluster of computers on which I am not an admin. I'm asking here because my attempts to google only provided comparisons to cython, unladen swallow, ect., and I don't want to bug the admin about it if this is unlikely to work.

PyPy will only make noticeable performance improvements if your code is CPU bound. PyPy is the [fastest](http://speed.pypy.org/) Python implementation I know of that runs natively. You could investigate some of the [other implementations](http://python.org/download/), or consider writing C extensions if true threading parallelism is a high priority for you.

> I don't actually need pypy to be as good at C; I'm looking to use it because right now the interpreter's overhead is completely overshadowing the computation I'm trying to time. I just need pypy to get me in the neighborhood of handwritten C.

Closing the performance gap with C is currently PyPy's single greatest feature. I highly recommend you try it out.

Comment: I did eventually just try pypy and unfortunately it did not speed things up substantially and I had to rewrite the code in C. Thank you for your post, it was very informative.

Comment: @blackfedora: Hey I'm glad :). You'll be a much better programmer for having tried to make it work.

Comment: pypy has some issues with external dependancies, it think. If u have a lot external dependancies, u probably get more issues to solve than CPython. Unlike CPython, not all libraries are not available (or not up to date) for pypy

Answer (score 1):

It should handle sockets and threads rather quickly, I cannot assure you that it's going to be as fast as C, PyPy uses guards to make sure the values are acceptable to run in the C function. Because PyPy uses a JIT, It will offer the most performance gain in cases of large loops. You might have a look at [pypy's speed tests here](http://speed.pypy.org/)

Comment: I saw those benchmarks but was hoping to see some comparing pypy to c and python as the most recent benchmarks of that kind date back many versions of pypy. I'm going to go ahead and try pypy; I'll post back here with at least some benchmarks comparing pypy to python.

Answer (score -4):

The problem lies not so much in calling routines in standard APIs as much as the pypy processing in-between. The less pypy processing the more you're going to approach C speed (since once execution has entered the actual API code there is no difference in execution speed). I wouldn't expect miracles though.

I found [this comparison](http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/) of how different programming languages fare against each other and although pypy is not included, python is and doesn't do all that well in terms of raw speed.

Comment: Programming languages do not have performance characteristics; execution machinery do. This is why the question asks about PyPy, not CPython.

Comment: @Marcin: he did ask about pypy relative to C and assuming testing the execution speed of both on the same "execution machinery" (same computer) a relative performance measure should be the result.

Comment: Unless you run all of your programs right in the processor, there is more execution machinery. CPython and PyPy are not the same thing, and are known to have different performance characteristics.

Comment: To understand how PyPy performance can be completely different from CPython, see http://speed.pypy.org/, as suggested by bluemoon.

Comment: @Marcin: AFAIK pypy is a variant of python and since the comparison contains many different programming languages I thought it might be useful. I have not mentioned CPython anywhere, you have. What I have mentioned is C (as in the original question: he didn't ask about CPython either). C is NOT the same as CPython (which I have never heard of). I think you've lost me.

Comment: @OlofForshell I lost you before I spoke, because you have no idea what is going on here. Python is a language; pypy and cpython are implementations of python execution machinery. There is no such thing as a comparison of the performance of C vs python, because those are an abstract set of rules. There are comparisons of the performance of execution machinery, so C compiled using e.g. GCC running on e.g. Windows 7, running on e.g. x84-64 vs Python running on e.g. CPython running on e.g. Windows 7, running on e.g. x84-64. You linked to a comparison which uses CPython 3.2.2.

Comment: @OlofForshell That has almost no relevance whatsoever to the performance of either CPython 2.7 or PyPy, given that those are different implementations of a different programming language.

Comment: @Marcin: I beg to differ. It is absolutely possible to compare the execution time of a program written in C and generated for this or that target environment with the execution time of an interpreted (bytecode or other) program written in an interpreted (bytecode or other) language and executed by "execution machinery" on the same target environment. I see such comparions relatively often, actually. Usually with discussions on how C executes faster but takes longer to write and vice versa for the interpreted (bytecode or other) language. The original question DID mention C.

Comment: @OlofForshell Are you deliberately being obtuse? In no way am I saying that it is impossible to measure the performance of a particular executable generated from C code - I am saying that that is the only possible measurement, because there is no such thing as measurement of the performance of a language.

Comment: @Marcin: the op was wondering about aspects of the performance of C vs normal python. I attempted to assist in doing that along with a few bits of own experiences. I fail to see you contributing here other than to muddy things by offering that python is interpreted and C is not. So what? I believe the questions were about 1. if pypy handles sockets efficiently compared to C and 2. how an app written in python should be written to have the least performance disadvantage over one written in C. I answered both and referred to comparison data for the second.

Comment: @OlofForshell I don't know what "normal python" is, but I do know that the OP asks about PyPy, not the python implementation used in the comparison you linked. Accordingly, not only does your answer not qualify as an answer because of the category error you persist in, it also fails because you cite irrelevant data.